# problems while deploying to ec2 with rubber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2

Folks,

I am having some problems while deploying to ec2 using the rubber gem. My development machine is ubuntu, I am using rvm.

When I do this:

```
cap rubber:create_staging
```

I get:

/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:926:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem capistrano (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:244:in`activate_dep'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:236:in `activate'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1307:in`gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/cap:18
Does anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Like Sairam says in his/her comment above, you need to install the Capistrano gem locally.

You can either do this by running "gem install capistrano" or adding Capistrano to your Gemfile and running "bundle update".